# How do I load data via Azure Data Factory "Copy data" without interrupting shares?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Azure Data Factory pipeline that is using the "Copy data" Snowflake connector to move data from a table in our Azure SQL Database into a table in our Snowflake database. The process is that we truncate the snowflake table (via pre-copy script in the copy data activity), then proceed with the import of the data pulled from the Azure DB. The problem is that this part of the "copy data" activity can take an extended period of time (an hour or more) due to the amount of data, and so my understanding is that if we have a share created against this data, consumers of the data will see no results during this "downtime". Is there a recommended approach where we can eliminate this "downtime" so that consumers aren't affected during this refresh of the data until it is 100% complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use a ZERO-COPY CLONE as part of your workflow.  It's a bit more statements to be executed, but you'd do something like this initially:

1. Copy into table {table_name_load}
2. Clone table using `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {table_name} CLONE {table_name_load}`
3. Grant {table_name} to share

This creates a copy of the table you are loading with, but without actually duplicating your data.  When you incrementally run, you'd follow the same steps, but with the truncate:

1. truncate {table_name_load}
2. copy into table {table_name_load}
3. Clone table using `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {table_name} CLONE {table_name_load}`
4. Grant {table_name} to share

Note: your downtime for your consumers of the share will only be for the length of time that #3 and #4 take to execute, which should be a second or 2.

Also Note: Step #4 is necessary, since the {table_name} object is new each time you create the new clone, so it will need to be re-added to your share.